# Filter Dashing API call

Tags: teamcity, webhooks, dashing

We have a Teamcity build server which publishes updates to Dashing through Webhooks. But we don't want to display every update as we are only interested in the status of the main branch.

Is there a way to intercept the API call, and then stop the update based on the data?

Answer (score 0):

The API is incredibly simplistic and meant to provide rudimentary support for odd use-cases like user input. You cannot filter.

Dashing is meant to Pull data, not have data Pushed to it. If you were pulling data into your widgets via a standard Ruby job, you could filter the input.

TeamCity has a REST api: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API

Use this to API pull data into your Dashing Dashboard with a Ruby job.